# Employing Post Method in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Using the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import beautiful_soup_tidal

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form_submit.html')

@app.route('/richmond', methods=['POST'])
def richmond():
    someTides = beautiful_soup_tidal.getTides()
    return render_template('richmond.html',someTides=someTides)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And attempting to render the following (richmond.html):

```
<div id="content" class="form-group">
    <form method="post" action="/richmond">

        <label style="vertical-align: middle;">channel depth at mean low water
        <input type="number" step="0.1" value = "34.5" name="channelDepth"/>FEET</label><br><br>

        <label style="vertical-align: middle;">required underkeel clearance
        <input type="number" step="0.1" value = "2" name="underkeelClearance"/>FEET</label><br><br>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

I get the following error: 'The method is not allowed for the requested URL.'

If I delete ', methods=['POST']' in the first section the template renders.

The question: How do I render the template successfully using the post method?

Comment: You have to submit a POST request. That's typically done by submitting a form. Clicking a link or typing the URL directly into your browser will submit a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe this line should also include GET so that you can render the html form first time round before you actually click submit to post it.

```
@app.route('/richmond', methods=['POST'])
```

so it would change to

```
@app.route('/richmond', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```